# Implement webdav for encrypted word document

Tags: http, encryption, webdav

I need to implement webdav in my application. So the user can edit word document, without need to download and back it upload to the server. However, the problem now, the document saved on webdav server are encrypted. Is it possible to use webdav for encrypted file?

Or another words, is it possible to make http-GET request to encrypted file 
2080.enc (which actually encrypted word document)

[GET] /DAV/2016/02/2080.enc

and get a decrypted file word document as a response, so I can edit the word document? Many thanks

Regards

===============================================================

===============================================================

Here is actually the problem..

On the client side, I am going to download the document stored on webdav server like this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="return officelink('@url')"> @item.GetDocumentActionTitle </a>
 <object id="winFirefoxPlugin" type="application/x-sharepoint" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;"></object>

<script>
function officelink(sDocumentUrl) {
    $.get(sDocumentUrl, null, function (data) {
        try {
            new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.4").EditDocument(data);
            return false;
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin").EditDocument(data);
                return false;
            }
            catch (e2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, the url must be full path including domain name like this http://webdavserver.com/2016/02/2080.doc..

It work perfectly if it is a word document (2080.doc), however what actually stored in the server is NOT 2089.doc BUT 2080.sec (enrcypted word document)

If it is NOT word document, The function EditDocument wont be able to read the file. And later by saving the file, it must be encrypted as well

Can you understand my problem? What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: How is the file encrypted, using what method?

Comment: It use Rjandael algorithm

Comment: You'd likely have to implement your own WebDAV server that does the decryption, or decrypt it in your app. It's hard to say without more details.

Comment: Hi, Pekka.. I add more details in my quastion. I hope the problem is more understandable now